# Unable to get mentioned Time Format while exporting DateTable to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I am trying to export a DataTable to an Excel-file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. The problem is that,  I am able to get data of TimeStamp column but not in defined TimeFormat but with other format.

Even though i defined number format as  "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" , here i defined Time in 12hour, but after exporting I am getting in 24hour format , and tt is defined to get AM/PM value but in excel i am getting tt only

[image: ScreenShot of TimeStamp Column]

```
if (dataColumn.ColumnName == "Timestamp")
                {
                    DateTime[] result = data.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>()
                        .Select(row1 => Convert.ToDateTime(row1[dataColumn.ColumnName]))
                        .ToArray();


                    var data1 = new DateTime[result.Count(), 1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        data1[i, 0] = result[i];
                    }
                    var startCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row + 1, col];
                    var endCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row + result.Count(), col];
                    // worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Font.Bold = false;
                    worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell].NumberFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
                    worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Value = data1;
                }
```

Kindly provide suggestion to get required TimeFormat and tt to display AM/PM value in Timestamp Column

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time to a timestamp, for example: 2019/3/31 15:32:37 to 1554017557. There is no formatting problem after reading.